# Ouput modifier tags (price) as radio buttons

Tags: expresso-store

I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation and outputting price modifiers as radio buttons.

Im trying to build a make shift gift card thing since store doesn't support that yet.

I want radio buttons for the fixed amounts, and then a custom text field for any custom amount. I need it to be output as radio buttons and a text field. As long as it affects the price in the cart, the rest will be fine.

Been trying with the examples fmor the docs, but even the select list is giving me trouble.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure "Enable Dynamic Prices?" is set to Yes under Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Fields > Products > Product Details.

You can then submit a `price` field as part of your add to cart form:

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="123"}

    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="10" /> $10</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="20" /> $20</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="50" /> $50</label>

{/exp:store:product}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just posting here since others may wonder what I just had a problem with and found this topic.

Make sure if you're wanting to just use "{price}" for one of the options, appened it with _val or it'll just show up as $0.  It's easy to miss in the official docs.

- "{price}" = "$123.00" (won't work due to automatic formatting)
- "{price_val}" ="123.00"